# Access to Client Credential Flow (2-legged OAuth) of Linkedin API

Tags: linkedin-api

How to get access to LinkedIn API Client using Client Credential Flow [(2-legged OAuth)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow) when my usecase does not fit in one of the [LinkedIn partners scope](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply)? How/where should I apply to get access? Or does it mean only the 4 usecases in this link can use server-side-only access to LinkedIn (without explicit user authentication)?

Currently, when I try to authenticate and get an access token, I have the following error:

```
{
  "error": "access_denied",
  "error_description": "This application is not allowed to create application tokens"
}
```

My usecase is to save time in our internal process following an interview we had with entrepreneurs. We generate a report and, instead of manually picking their profile information from LinkedIn, we would like to pre-fill the report using the LinkedIn API.

The LinkedIn support redirects to either Stack Overflow for API support or [the link above](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply) to request access (which is for specific usecases only)

Resources:
- [Use of OAUth 2.0 Client Credentials Flow](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow)

Comment: If none of the partner programs are applicable towards your use case, your use case will not be approved.